# Google App Script Parse CSV giving error Exception: Could not parse text

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to read CVS files from given google drive folder and paste contents of the file into a spreadsheet. It works fine with all CSV files except one. Im attaching both code Im using and the csv file which is not being parsed with following error: **Exception: Could not parsewhile(files.hasNext())
ffiles.push(files.next());

```
for (var j=0;j<ffiles.length;j++){
  var file = ffiles[j];
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  writeDataToSheet(contents,dSheet,i)
  file.moveTo(mfolder);
} text.** `enter code here`
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HdRIYNzTjBvcOUum4o40vtZ0Imz0isZz/view?usp=sharing

CSV File is at link above.

Comment: You should be using the iterator methods  hasNext() and next() as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) rather that looping through them.

Comment: Other files are working fine. The issue is with one file formatting I dont know why it could not be parsed.